# Opening Simple screen recorder fills up the panel with multiple icons

Tags: unity, lubuntu, icons, panel

I have installed the lubuntu desktop today from the software center. I was using Unity and it was so slow for some reason. When I open simple screen recorder, the panel got filled with multiple icons of it. The screenshot is attached. This is not happening for any other application. I have tried chrome, brackets, panel settings etc. I have checked the system monitor app to see whether it is opened multiple times or not, but I could see only one entry there. [image]

Could somebody please help?

Comment: Unfortunately, after the second restart I cannot find the issue anymore :)

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, a similar thing happened to me.  I have Lubuntu 15.10 and the multiple panel icon thing happened to me with AutoKey.

IIRC, the way I got rid of it was to do a

> Ctrl+Alt+T

to bring up the Terminal.

Then I typed

> lxpanelctl restart

to restart the panel.

After this one time, it never happened again.